# White tests - folder browser dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, white-framework

I have problem with getting of FolderBrowserDialog in white. I think that it should be assigned as a modal window but it isn't.

FolderBrowserDialog in DialogService.cs:

```
 public FolderBrowserResult ShowFolderbrowserDialog(string storageFolder)
    {
        var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog
        {               
            Description = storageFolder
        };

        var result = new FolderBrowserResult
        {
            Result = dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK,
            Path = dialog.SelectedPath          
        };

        return result;
    }
```

Method called after click on browse button:

```
private void OnBrowseForTargetFolder(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = dialogService.ShowFolderbrowserDialog(Properties.Resources.StorageFolder);
        if (result.Result) return;

        Project.PathToStorage = result.Path;
        completePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", result.Path, Guid.NewGuid());
        Directory.CreateDirectory(completePath);
    }
```

Test:

```
public class LoggerTests
{
    private Application application;

    private MainWindowPage mainWindowPage;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        application = Application.Launch(@"PML.exe");
        StartBlankApplication();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void StartExistingProject()
    {
        mainWindowPage.StartExistingProjectButton.Click();
        var modalWindows = new List<Window>();
        Retry.For(() =>
        {
            modalWindows = mainWindowPage.applicationWindow.ModalWindows();
        }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        var mod = modalWindows;
    }

    private MainWindowPage StartBlankApplication()
    {
        var appWindow = application.GetWindow("PML");
        mainWindowPage = new MainWindowPage(appWindow);
        return mainWindowPage;
    }

    private NewProjectConfigurationPage ConfigureBlankProject()
    {
        Window secondAppWindow = null;
        Retry.For(() =>
        {
            secondAppWindow = application.GetWindow("PML");
        }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        var newProjectConfiguration = new NewProjectConfigurationPage(secondAppWindow);

        newProjectConfiguration.VesselName.Text = "Test";
        newProjectConfiguration.BrowseButton.Click();

        return newProjectConfiguration;
    }
}
```

In *StartExistingProject* method is problem that variable *mod* is empty. And no FolderBrowserDialog is opened. But when I run app normally everything runs OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - There must be setted owner to modal dialog. So

```
 var wrapper = new WindowWrapper(this);

 dialog.ShowDialog(wrapper)
```

solved my problem.